# avoid repeating adding the line more than one time

Tags: jquery, selector

Is there any solution, to avoid repeating adding the line more than one time in each form, in case the code was run more than one time .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(($("CarID").length) == 0) {
            $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="CarForm" id="CarID" value="#session.CarForm#" />');
                        }
                    });
```

I am new to jQuery, Please advise me .

Answer (score 0):

I will use :

```
if(!this.done){
        this.done =true;

        $(document).ready(function() {
               if(($("CarID").length) == 0) {
                   $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="CarForm" id="CarID" value="#session.CarForm#" />');
                                            }
                        });
             }
```